# scriptcs - Unable to read package

Tags: jquery, nuget, scriptcs

I followed a [blog post](http://inaspiralarray.blogspot.com/2013/08/scriptcs-in-two-minutes.html) to get scriptcs running in just two steps. Basically, I did this:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "iex ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin
```

And then I got an error when doing this:

```
cinst scriptcs
```

> Unable to read package from path 'jQuery.2.0.1.1.nupkg'.

This worked on a different machine, but it's failing on my current laptop. Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

**EDIT**

As per Damian's answer, below, I just had to delete the contents of the NuGet cache, located here:

> C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache

Comment: That's weird. Can you try cinst scriptcs -pre -source https://www.myget.org/F/scriptcsnightly/ ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This bug](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/issues/325) from the Chocolatey GitHub repo suggests that you need to clear the NuGet cache (**%LocalAppData%\NuGet\Cache**) and this should resolve itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please try-

- Clean **scriptcs_packages** folder.
- Clean **scriptcs_packages.config** file.
- Then reinstall all packages needed .

Run scriptcs